# How to upgrade nautilus to 3.4 on 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, nautilus, package-management, dependencies

I'd like to upgrade Nautilus from 2.32.2.1 to 3.4 because I've encountered a [problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162580/ftp-via-nautilus-can-not-paste-files) which I cannot reproduce on Nautilus 3.4 (on Ubuntu 12.04). I guess there might be a bug in my current version.

The problem is that I'm not that sure if I can simply install a newer version on Ubuntu Natty without causing trouble, because I don't want to change the whole desktop.
I took a look on the [package for Precise](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/nautilus/download) just to see if it works, but after following  a few dependencies I end up at the decision to destroy a package (libc-dev-bin) which I don't want to do with my little experience.

Is it even possible to upgrade and if yes, how could I achieve that?
(if you know some good explanations of the issue packages & dependencies please feel free to post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to 12.04 is *by far* the easiest way to get a new version of Nautilus.

Nautilus is an integral part of Gnome, which is an integral part of the whole distro, depending on a particular version of `libc` and other stuff. Trying to update only some of the packages will lead you straight into *dependency hell*, as you're already discovering, especially when migrating from Gnome2 to Gnome3.

Another option is compiling new version of Gnome from source with a separate prefix, but that's also probably more work that you'll be willing to invest.

Comment: Just as I feared. I already tried 12.04 on my pc but ran into problems/crashes so I wanted to stay on 11.04 for longer. Seems I have to give it another try =) thanks for your answer.